# Type Mismatch Error Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently running a VBA script in excel to allow for specific username and password access to specific sheets. I was following this tutorial on youtube and everything seemed to be going well until I began encountering errors.

I am getting a Type mismatch error in my code, which is below. There are two lines that are giving me errors, they are **commented**, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckUser()
Dim UserRow, SheetCol As Long
Dim SheetNm As String
    With Sheet34
        .Calculate

        If .Range("B6").Value = Empty Then    'Incorrect Username
            MsgBox "Please enter a correct username"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If .Range("B5").Value <> True Then    'Incorrect Password
            MsgBox "Please enter a correct password"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        UserForm1.Hide
        UserRow = .Range("b6").Value    'userrow

        .Range("B3").Value = ""
        .Range("b4").Value = ""

        For SheetCol = 6 To 26
            SheetNm = .Cells(2, SheetCol).Value    'SheetName

            If .Cells(UserRow, SheetCol).Value = "Ð" Then   ' line where error occurs
                Sheets(SheetNm).Protect "TEP2003"
                Sheets(SheetNm).Visible = xlSheetVisible
            End If

            If .Cells(UserRow, SheetCol).Value = "Ï" Then    ' line where error occurs
                Sheets(SheetNm).Visible = xlVeryHidden
            End If

        Next SheetCol
    End With
End Sub


Sub closeworkbook()
    Sheet1.Activate
    Dim WkSht As Worksheet
    For Each WkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WkSht.Name <> "Main" Then WkSht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Next WkSht
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Please consider better formatting.

Comment: What are the values of UserRow, SheetCol when the error occurs? And you might as well DIm UserRow As Long. It is currently implicitly a variant.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Range.Text property. Range.Text will not fix a worksheet error code but it will evaluate one as text where Range.Value will fail. Combine the two with an ElseIf; there is no point in evaluating the second if the first passes.

```
    ...
    If .Cells(UserRow, SheetCol).Text = "Ð" Then
    ...
    ElseIf .Cells(UserRow, SheetCol).Text = "I" Then
    ...
    End If
```